# Can't use PHP extension Mcrypt in Ubuntu 13.10 (Nginx, PHP-FPM)

Tags: php, nginx, laravel

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop. Like I usually do, I install the packages I need for Web development, which are nginx, php5-fpm, mysql, php5-mysql, php5-mcrypt and a few others.

After editing some configuration files, this usually works.

But today, since 13.10, an error appears instead of the Web page I expected.

```
Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.
```

The package php5-mcrypt has been installed and reinstalled.

The command `php -m` doesn't seem to show mcrypt.

Any idea where the problem could come from? I've done this setup many times and it always worked.

Comment: This is a bug report, ideally, and you should report the bug against `php5-mcrypt` with `ubuntu-bug php5-mcrypt`.

Comment: @Marc-François there is a typo in your edit to the accepted answer by Tom, instead of mods-avalaible it should be mods-available.

Comment: thx god, i thought im the only one having this issue..it drive me nuts...

Comment: This is a bug in `php-mcrypt` https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mcrypt/+bug/1240590

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the same problem after I upgraded to 13.10 this evening. Apparently this is a genuine Ubuntu 13.10 bug: “[phpmyadmin do not recognize php5-mcrypt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1236035)”. The PHP modules got moved from the `conf.d` directory to the `mods-available` directory, and the mcrypt module got left behind.

To fix it I put a symlink to the `mcrypt.ini` file in the PHP config.

#### Apache

If you use Apache (*rather than php-fpm*):

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### php-fpm

Or for php-fpm (*rather than Apache*):

1. Make symbolic link to ini files in mods-available

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
   ```
2. Enable mods

   ```
   sudo php5enmod mcrypt
   ```
3. Restart FPM

   ```
   sudo service php5-fpm restart
   ```

---

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Apache. Your other solution for PHP-FPM didn't work.

Comment: You were almost right. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mcrypt/+bug/1241286

Comment: oh my god thank you so much..i been trying for all solution i can found online but up to no avail..it drive me nuts..i almost give up..thx u

Comment: Wow... I had been fiddling with laravel for the past 2 days... just wow! Thank you Tom! Love the open source community

Comment: This doesn't seem to be required for 14.04 now. Still have to enable it though.

Comment: Wow I was always using **sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart** and wondering why it does not work. With **sudo service php5-fpm restart** it works instantly! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Or, use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Im not sure of this will work on standard php installs - I installed php 5.5.7 using the package from:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
```