# Ubuntu-Lampp PHP path issue

Tags: 13.10, php, lamp

I use Ubuntu 13.10 and Lampp.

When I try to run `sudo php artisan job-daemon` I get the above message. But when I run `php artisan job-daemon` it works just fine.

`php -m` gives me the following:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mssql
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sybase_ct
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

`which php` gives me the following:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php
```

Why do I get the message missing then?

I ran

```
johnnemo@johnnemo:~$ sudo nano .bashhrc
```

I added

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/php
```

but still no luck....Any ideas..?

$PATH and sudo $PATH :

```
sudo: /opt/lampp/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: command not found


johnnemo@johnnemo:~$ $PATH
bash: /opt/lampp/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try running `sudo which php` as the problem only exists when `sudo` was on the original command. This means it is probably a user related issue.

Comment: I get /usr/bin/php

Comment: So there is your answer ;)

Comment: How can I change it for sudo to be the same...

Comment: Why are you using LAMPP over straight php from Ubuntu?

Comment: I don t know I just started it this way to have php my admin...Can I have it without lampp..?

Comment: Yes, `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` will install phpmyadmin. Almost everything you're using LAMPP for comes built in a package.

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH
```

NOT

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

Basically, the order matters. It now first looks in the /opt/lampp/bin folder to find certain executables and THEN looks at the original paths.

Comment: Explain **why** that would help!

Comment: Basically, the order matters. It now first looks in the /opt/lampp/bin folder to find certain executables and THEN look at the original paths.

Comment: The explanation belongs into the answer - you can edit it any time.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the problem is that the PATH is different for the User account and the root account. Try editing the rood bash profile file:

```
/root/.bashrc
```

At the bottom add the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

To set the path for when `sudo` is running. Then source the profile:

```
sudo source /root/.bashrc
```

Comment: I just opened it and there are so many things...What should I change..?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, edited above.

Comment: which php is still different than sudo which php

Comment: Try sourcing the new profile, see above.

Comment: No...I still have the same problem..

Comment: What is this difference between `sudo $PATH` and `$PATH` when run in the terminal?

Comment: Sorry..I just edited my question..

Comment: URG. That all looks good. It still shows `/usr/bin/php` when you run `sudo which php`?

Comment: Unfortunately Yes...:(

Comment: Wait one thing is a little fishy. The path shouldn’t have the last `/php` (updated in post), change that and source again. Then if that doesn't work as a hack run just run `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php artisan job-daemon` instead.

Comment: No luck....Thank you though

Comment: No luck with either? I am stumped. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:

[mcrypt in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360646/cant-use-php-extension-mcrypt-in-ubuntu-13-10-nginx-php-fpm)

The PHP modules got moved from the conf.d directory to the mods-available directory, and the mcrypt module got left behind.

Comment: So it is not a path problem..?But unlikely the other post when I run php-m I can see the mcrypt..