# phpenmod mcrypt and phpenmod mbstring return errors

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I use a minimal server environment of ubuntu16.04.1, Apache2, MySQL and PHP 7.0.8.1. I've installem AMP via: `apt-get install lamp-server^`.

I also installed PHPmyadmin manually via:

```
cd /var/www/html
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.6.5.2/phpMyAdmin-4.6.5.2-all-languages.zip
find ./ -type f -name '*phpMyAdmin*.zip' -exec unzip {} \; # We can also do unzip \*phpMyAdmin*.zip ...
find ./ -type d -name 'phpMyAdmin-*' -exec mv {} phpmyadmin \;
```

PHPmyadmin is bootstrapped but to use it fully functionally, AFAIK I aslo need to do:

```
phpenmod mcrypt
phpenmod mbstring
```

Yet these respectively return errors:

```
Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available

Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
```

I never had these errors before. Are these modules redundant for PHPmyadmin in current releases or when not installed via `apt-get install`?

Comment: try `sudo a2enmod mcrypt` and `sudo a2enmod mbstring`

Comment: You did install `php-mcrypt` and `php-mbstring`, right?

Comment: Is the issue resolved ?

Comment: It seems I can access PMA without installing these as you shown in the answer so I wonder if there is an issue at all (the only reason I wanted to install this is because I thought they are missing for PMA but it seems in latest releases we just dont need them).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install them first:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-mcrypt && sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring
```

Then enable them with:

```
sudo a2enmod mcrypt
sudo a2enmod mbstring
```

**Update**

Based on the extensive research I believe a **bug** exist that prevents your *php cli* working well with *php mcrypt*.

Source:

[Can't use PHP extension Mcrypt in Ubuntu 13.10 (Nginx, PHP-FPM)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360646/cant-use-php-extension-mcrypt-in-ubuntu-13-10-nginx-php-fpm)

[php is not working well on ubuntu 13.10 and mcrypt is missing in phpmyadmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362082/php-is-not-working-well-on-ubuntu-13-10-and-mcrypt-is-missing-in-phpmyadmin)

To confirm that `mcrypt` is *enabled* in apache follow these steps:

1. Create a `php` file called `info.php` put this code in it:

   ```
   <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
   ```
2. Put the file in `/var/www/html` or your *server root*
3. Access it from the brower at say `IP/info.php` or `localhost/info.php`
4. Look at the out and you will find that `mcrypt and mbstring` are enabled

   [image]

   As you can see, its enabled in apache, but inaccessible from php CLI hence the error messages.
5. To confirm its working **[as I have this problem also]** I did the following:

   - installed *prestashop* application, and since one of the *requirements* of prestashop is **php mcrypt** it would have thrown an error and refused to proceed if `mcrypt` was not enabled on *apache*.

Simple put based on your the if your *apache information page* displays these *modules* as enabled then it is. The error seen are a result of *php CLI* having issues with *mcrypt* which has been noted to be a bug. Seen in earlier versions of *php* but now present in *php 7*

Comment: Brings `ERROR: Module mcrypt does not exist!`.

Comment: what version of `php` are you using ?

Comment: I use version 7.0.8.

Comment: Then do `sudo apt install php7.0-mcrypt && sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring` its like its not installed.

Comment: Wired, I was sure they would be installed with PHP7 from my command above. Maybe it's a temporary bug?

Comment: Never assume any thing with computers or software, just double check to be sure.

Comment: Thumbed up! Adding a soft shortlink solved it.

Comment: @Benia AFAIK doing `sudo a2enmod module_name` actually does the same thing as `ln -s /etc/php7/conf.d/module.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/module.ini`. So simple doing `a2enmod` will create that _symbolic link_ for you.

Comment: Reposting: Looking back, creating symlinks as in Arduino_sentinel's answer is not enough and I first need to install these, as in George's answer. Both answers are correct.

Comment: George, I'll check this asap.

Comment: You may also check in `/etc/php7/apache2/conf.d`, similar to `/etc/php7/conf.d/` depending on your system.

Comment: Wired, I've installed a new server environment from a script but now either `a2enmod` or `ln -s` works... Yet when I try to reinstall I get (for example): `php7.0-mcrypt is already the newest version (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.` ... I just tried to upgrade and it didn't help --- Both methods still don't work. Moreover, after upgrading I get `update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults`.

Comment: How do you know its not working ? It says __already newest version__ hence its there already. The `update-rc.d` is for the __old Upstart system__, you should be using `systemd` in Ubuntu 16.04. Hence if you want to say reload _apache2_ you would do `sudo systemctl restart apache2` rather than `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51171/discussion-between-george-and-benia).

Comment: I was wrong. The links are created, but still `ERROR: Module mbstring does not exist!`. `ERROR: Module mcrypt does not exist!`.

Comment: If you receive this comment respond found a solution.

Comment: Sure, entering to chat.

Comment: Replied there now.

Answer (score 5):

I had issues with the above solutions but found this:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-7-2/

Essentially, build it yourself:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
```

Once the dependencies have been installed, you can install mcrypt with the command:

```
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

From there I needed to add:

```
 /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
```

Which looked like this:

```
; configuration for php mcrypt module
; priority=20
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Then

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: this solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If their both installed and the error persist, Try to make a symlink to ini files in `mods-available`

Here is how to do it:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php7/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mcrypt.ini

sudo ln -s /etc/php7/conf.d/mbstring.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mbstring.ini
```